# Validation rule on Account

Tags: validation-rule

I created a validation rule on Account, to check if the Account site is blank.. When I update an existing opportunity associated to that account i don't get the error (VR message) on the Opportunity record, but when I create a new opportunity for that account it is throwing the VR message (Account site is blank for that account).. VR is working correctly but it is firing when I create a new oppty...

I disabled all Oppty triggers and tested it, but it still throws that error...

Can you please suggest why I am noticing this behavior or is it the way it works...

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

The VR on Account shouldn't fire on Opportunity update/create at all. It should only fire, in case the account record is about to be updated/created. So I still assume that somehow (trigger, workflow, etc) the Opportunity creation is causing an Account update.

You could setup the same validation in a brand new free DE org, which comes without anything interfering out of the box. Or have a look at the last modified date: does it update after Opportunity creation?

If it's working there, you need to look very carefully through your workflows and triggers again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. I disabled all triggers in Account and Opportunity. I turned on the debug log... It is very strange, it executed in the below order: 1. Oppty VR 2. Oppty WRK FLOW (all criteria failed for WRKFLW) 3. Finally it started firing the Account validation rule.. So normally when you create a new opportunity for the first time does it update the Account record as well..

Comment: Do you use rollup summary fields? These also trigger validation rules in the parent object.

Comment: To be explicit: out-of-the-box the creation of a new Opportunity should **not** update the Account record. Try this in a brand new DE just to proof it.